# Convert a string to be readable as a linq object

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

This is a school assignment that I am trying to keep as flexible as possible so that I can refer back to it in the future.

I am trying to write a program that uses a combobox to pass a string to a Linq query.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    ContractDataGridView.DataSource = Nothing

    Dim currValue As Linq.Contract = "aContract." & ComboBox1.Text 'error is here with the literal and returned value
    'Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'Linq.Contract'.
    Dim db As New myDatabaseDataContext
    Dim query = From aContract In db.Contracts
                Select currValue
                Order By aContract.ContractAmt


    ContractDataGridView.DataSource = query    
End Sub
```

I know how to brute force it. I would rather have something a little more flexible if possible.

Comment: What is `Linq.Contract`? My IDE doesn't recognize it and I can't find any documentation. :-/

Comment: My original code was
    Dim currValue As String = "aContract." & ComboBox1.Text 
and 
    Order By currValue
The query was run without the Order By executing

Comment: Okay great. That didn't answer my question. I take it your code snippet isn't supposed to make sense? Could you try to clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to populate a datagrid with a query. I want to use a string as part of that query. Linq.Contract was an attempt to format that string to something that the query would read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to use the string '"aContract." & ComboBox1.Text' as the name of the column to `Order By`?  If so, you are trying to create a dynamic Linq query which is complex (and, I'd guess, not akin to the level of effort you'd be trying to put into this).  Check out http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx for a whole library that supports doing things like this.

What would help is to try and explain a bit more what you're trying to use the '"aContract." & ComboBox1.Text' value to accomplish.

Comment: Yes! I want to dynamically name the column to Order By. I don't know why I couldn't formulate that better. Select should be currValue and not aContract. I'll make the edit. And yes, it probably is more effort than I would normally want to invest for this project. I feel like knowing how to create a dynamic linq query may be handy in the future.